# Why is .Equal False when i expect it to be true?

Tags: c#, .net

The first line is true, the second is false. htmlOut and s2 are StringWriter objects.

```
    bool b = s2.ToString() == htmlOut.ToString();
    ret = htmlOut.Equals(s2);
```

I expected true which b is but why is ret false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

StringWriter doesn't override object.Equals.

```
htmlOut.Equals(s2);
```

is equivalent to :

```
object.ReferenceEquals(htmlOut, s2);
```

Comment: Not exactly. `htmlOut.Equals(s2);` will throw a `NullReferenceException` if `htmlOut` is `null` while `object.ReferenceEquals(htmlOut, s2);` will not.

Answer (score 9):

`StringWriter` uses an internal `StringBuilder` to write to. `StringWriter.ToString()` returns the string built by `StringBuilder`.

`StringWriter` does not override `object.Equals()` so `StringWriter.Equals()` compares if the two objects are the same reference, not if their string representations are equal.

Comment: so with StringWriter .Equals is the same as == ?

Comment: `StringWriter` does not implement the `==` operator which defaults to reference equality, too, so yes.

Answer (score 2):

The default implementation of Equals supports reference equality for reference types, and bitwise equality for value types.  Does the type of htmlOut have a non-default overridden Equals method?

In this case, it seems not, and it's telling you that they are different instances, whether or not their semantic values match up.

Answer (score 1):

```
htmlOut.ToString().Equals(s2.ToString());
```

this will return true